# How to select part of the text of a TextBlock control?

Tags: c#, uwp, textblock

I have a UWP Desktop application that has a TextBlock control with a very long text. The application has a search option, where the user types a word and the application must select the first occurrence of the word in the text. In a TextBox it is very easy, because the Select method takes two integers as parameters. But in the Select method of the TextBlock the parameters are TextPointers. How do I make this selection?

Comment: So, you problem is you don't know how to get selected text TextPointers right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how to select a part of the text from a TextBlock using TextPointers. I would like an example of the Select method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `TextHighlighter` with `TextRange`s to the `TextHighlighters` of the `TextBlock`, e.g.:

```
var wordToSelect = "long";
var index = tb.Text.IndexOf(wordToSelect);
if (index > -1)
{
    var textRange = new TextRange() { StartIndex = index, Length = wordToSelect.Length };
    var textHighlighter = new TextHighlighter();
    textHighlighter.Ranges.Add(textRange);
    tb.TextHighlighters.Add(textHighlighter);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="some long text" />
```